# Django: Adding and Saving new Data in Account Update for User Profile

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to add new information such as Facebook account related to a user. I have not added it in the registration form as it is not mandatory and no need to be there but if user wanted to add it, it can be found in account update as an option empty fields to be filled.

My issue is, I have added the facebook account to be in the account update profile but after I submit the update button, the page is refreshed and the data is not saved and it is not available in DB.

Here is the models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
```

Here is the views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(
                request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

Here is the forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        user_count = User.objects.filter(email=email).count()
        if user_count > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "This email has already been registered. Please check and try again or reset your password")
        return email

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    facebook_account = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'facebook_account']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

here is the signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

here is the template:

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="container" style="padding-top:100px">
        <div class="media">
            <img src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" class="rounded-circle">
            <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
                <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4 pt-4">Profile Info</legend>
                {{ u_form|crispy }}
                {{ p_form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
            </div>        
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Where is the field to save your additional information  in your model ?

Comment: I don't see any `facebook_account` field in your models, is that a typo or something?

Comment: it is in the UserUpdateForm

Comment: @A_K it should be in the model too